# How to get this mode with a boolean filter?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm exploring a data set, and want the mode of a 'Sex' column only when the subject answered X ('cute' in this case).

So far, I've done some stuff with the following logic. Got dummies from 'Sex', having a 'Male' (0,1) column. From there, I tried to do...

```
i_1_1 = clean_USA['Male'][clean_USA['Image1_1']=='cute']
i_mode = i_1_1.mode()
```

I've tried several things, but continue to fail. This time I got "KeyError: 'Male'" as an output. Maybe this in R would seem sth like:

```
i_1 <- mode(clean_USA$Male(clean_USA$Image1_1=='cute'))
```

Maybe, maybe not. I'm just starting to code, so I'd really appreciate some suggestions. How would you solve this problem?

Here's my head of df:

```
{'Nationality': {0: 'United States',
  1: 'United States',
  2: 'United States',
  3: 'United States',
  4: 'United States'},
 'Sex': {0: 'Female', 1: 'Female', 2: 'Female', 3: 'Female', 4: 'Female'},
 'Age': {0: 62, 1: 43, 2: 47, 3: 26, 4: 34},
 'Image1_1': {0: 'noun', 1: 'cute', 2: 'cute', 3: 'noun', 4: 'pretty'},
 'Image1_2': {0: 'cute', 1: 'happy', 2: 'lovely', 3: 'noun', 4: 'stunning'},
 'Image1_3': {0: 'happy', 1: 'clean', 2: 'crazy', 3: 'verb', 4: 'cute'},
 'Image2_1': {0: 'noun', 1: 'beautiful', 2: 'nice', 3: 'happy', 4: 'cute'},
 'Image2_2': {0: 'calm', 1: 'nice', 2: 'funny', 3: 'noun', 4: 'calm'},
 'Image2_3': {0: 'funny', 1: 'happy', 2: 'excited', 3: 'good', 4: 'lovely'},
 'Image3_1': {0: 'noun', 1: 'beautiful', 2: 'verb', 3: 'noun', 4: 'gorgeous'},
 'Image3_2': {0: 'happy', 1: 'happy', 2: 'faithful', 3: 'young', 4: 'elegant'},
 'Image3_3': {0: 'excited', 1: 'verb', 2: 'funny', 3: 'teen', 4: 'knockout'},
 'Image4_1': {0: 'noun', 1: 'worried', 2: 'super', 3: 'sad', 4: 'lovely'},
 'Image4_2': {0: 'noun', 1: 'lazy', 2: 'nice', 3: 'noun', 4: 'cute'},
 'Image4_3': {0: 'funny', 1: 'cute', 2: 'kind', 3: 'noun', 4: 'lovely'},
 'Image5_1': {0: 'noun', 1: 'cute', 2: 'crazy', 3: 'noun', 4: 'taking'},
 'Image5_2': {0: 'cute', 1: 'happy', 2: 'cute', 3: 'noun', 4: 'bonny'},
 'Image5_3': {0: 'calm', 1: 'nice', 2: 'lovely', 3: 'noun', 4: 'exquisite'},
 'Image6_1': {0: 'noun', 1: 'wonderful', 2: 'colorful', 3: 'happy', 4: 'good'},
 'Image6_2': {0: 'verb', 1: 'nice', 2: 'great', 3: 'positive', 4: 'fine'},
 'Image6_3': {0: 'calm',
  1: 'happy',
  2: 'temporary',
  3: 'optimistic',
  4: 'nice'},
 'Image7_1': {0: 'old', 1: 'clean', 2: 'lucky', 3: 'noun', 4: 'noun'},
 'Image7_2': {0: 'noun', 1: 'chubby', 2: 'obedient', 3: 'verb', 4: 'likely'},
 'Image7_3': {0: 'calm', 1: 'happy', 2: 'verb', 3: 'old', 4: 'nonword'},
 'Image8_2': {0: 'verb', 1: 'sweet', 2: 'tasty', 3: 'bake', 4: 'smooth'},
 'Image8_3': {0: 'taste', 1: 'nice', 2: 'delicious', 3: 'noun', 4: 'soft'},
 'Male': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: try **:**  `i_1_1=clean_USA[(clean_USA['Image1_1']=='cute') | (clean_USA['Sex']=='Male')]`

Comment: Hey Anurag, thanks for your answer. I still get the same error as an output, I think it has to do with trying to apply the filter that has as an output a Series, to a DataFrame. Could this be? Another error I got was: _"TypeError: Indexing a Series with DataFrame is not supported, use the appropriate DataFrame column"_

Comment: can you add the output of `df.head()` in your question?

Comment: Sure, there it goes

Comment: Sorry but table is not formatted so post the output of `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: use: `df.loc[(df['Image1_1']=='cute'),'Male'].mode()` **OR** `df.loc[(df['Image1_1']=='cute') & (df['Sex']=='Male'),'Male'].mode()` use any one of them according to your need as there is a column named 'Male' so it is a little bit confusing that you are talikg about Sex=='Male' or just the 'Male' column

Comment: I did, but still returns: _KeyError: "None of [Index([('I', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', '1', '_', '1'), ('I', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', '1', '_', '1')], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"_ :(

Answer (score 1):

IIUC this is what you want.

```
df.loc[df.Image1_1 == "cute", ["Sex"]].mode()

      Sex
0  Female
```

Not sure what the point of indexing `Male` is when you want the `mode` of the column. If you exclude all values but one, then the mode is just that value.

Comment: You did! Thanks for your answer, I'm saving time and code. So, I've loved this elegant snippet but still gives as an output:
_KeyError: "None of [Index([('I', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', '1', '_', '1'), ('I', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', '1', '_', '1')], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"_

Comment: whatever data you actually have does not match what you posted then, because I used the snippet you posted and it works as expected

Comment: I've copied from the notebook :( I'll try to figure

Answer (score 0):

whatever it is that you want to do, you cannot access a 'Male' column before creating it. But I'm guessing it isn't neccessary to create new columns.

If I understood correctly, you want this:

```
i_1_1 = clean_USA[clean_USA['Image1_1']=='cute']
i_mode = i_1_1['Sex'].mode()
```

Edit:
So you created the column and I just didn't see it. Then it should look like this.

```
i_1_1 = clean_USA[clean_USA['Image1_1']=='cute']
i_mode = i_1_1['Male'].mode()
```

Comment: Hello, examiner. For the first part, not really bc the column was created previously, check the head of the df, last column. For the second one, you're right and thanks